# how to display MySQL database values in html table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I am making a page for a website and I'm trying to display all the reservations that a specific user from a MySQL database, I already have the code (see below), but I cannot figure out how to display the database values on the table using php code, what do I have to do in order that the table works?

```
<?php 
session_start();

$nome_titular = $_SESSION['nome_titular'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AlojArt Reservas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendors/form-helpers/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendors/select/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendors/tags/css/bootstrap-tags.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/forms.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-5">
                  <!-- Logo -->
                  <div class="logo">
                     <h1><a href="dashboard.php">AlojArt Reservas</a></h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="input-group form">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
                      <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?= $nome_titular.' ' ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInUp">
                              <li><a href="profile.php">A minha conta</a></li>
                              <li><a href="logout.php">Terminar sessão</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </nav>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <!-- Main menu -->
                    <li><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Início</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu">
                         <a href="#">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i> Reservas
                            <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                         </a>
                         <!-- Sub menu -->
                         <ul>
                            <li><a href="history.php">Histórico</a></li>
                            <li><a href="reservations.php">Reservar</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="content-box-large">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="panel-title">Reservar</div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID de reserva</th>
                                <th>ID do imóvel</th>
                                <th>Data de entrada</th>
                                <th>Data de saída</th>
                                <th>Preço total</th>
                                <th>Data de consulta</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                <td>Trident</td>
                                <td>Internet
                                     Explorer 4.0</td>
                                <td>Win 95+</td>
                                <td class="center"> 4</td>
                                <td class="center">X</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even gradeC">
                                <td>Trident</td>
                                <td>Internet
                                     Explorer 5.0</td>
                                <td>Win 95+</td>
                                <td class="center">5</td>
                                <td class="center">C</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="odd gradeA">
                                <td>Trident</td>
                                <td>Internet
                                     Explorer 5.5</td>
                                <td>Win 95+</td>
                                <td class="center">5.5</td>
                                <td class="center">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even gradeA">
                                <td>Trident</td>
                                <td>Internet
                                     Explorer 6</td>
                                <td>Win 98+</td>
                                <td class="center">6</td>
                                <td class="center">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeA">
                                <td>Webkit</td>
                                <td>Safari 1.2</td>
                                <td>OSX.3</td>
                                <td class="center">125.5</td>
                                <td class="center">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                <td>Tasman</td>
                                <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
                                <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">X</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeC">
                                <td>Tasman</td>
                                <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
                                <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
                                <td class="center">1</td>
                                <td class="center">C</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeC">
                                <td>Tasman</td>
                                <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
                                <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
                                <td class="center">1</td>
                                <td class="center">C</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeA">
                                <td>Misc</td>
                                <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
                                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">C</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeA">
                                <td>Misc</td>
                                <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
                                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                <td>Misc</td>
                                <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
                                <td>Embedded devices</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">X</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                <td>Misc</td>
                                <td>Links</td>
                                <td>Text only</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">X</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                <td>Misc</td>
                                <td>Lynx</td>
                                <td>Text only</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">X</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeC">
                                <td>Misc</td>
                                <td>IE Mobile</td>
                                <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">C</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeC">
                                <td>Misc</td>
                                <td>PSP browser</td>
                                <td>PSP</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">C</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="gradeU">
                                <td>Other browsers</td>
                                <td>All others</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td class="center">-</td>
                                <td class="center">U</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

                                <div class="row"></div>

                            </fieldset>
                                    <div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
         <div class="container">

            <div class="copy text-center">
               Trabalho realizado por alunos do <a href='http://www.ispgaya.pt/site/'>ISPGAYA</a>
            </div>

         </div>
      </footer>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

edit: I was using a template hence the  values.

edit2: I added the followind code, and now i'm getting HTTP ERROR 500...

```
<div class="panel-title">Reservar</div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>ID de reserva</td>
                                <td>ID do imóvel</td>
                                <td>Data de entrada</td>
                                <td>Data de saída</td>
                                <td>Preço total</td>
                                <td>Data de consulta</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                        <?php
                            $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Informação WHERE nome_titular=$nome_titular LIMIT 10 ORDER BY id_reserva");
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
                        ?>

                            <tr>
                                <th><?php echo $row['id_reserva'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['id_imovel'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['data_entrada'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['data_saida'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['preco_total'] ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo $row['data_consulta'] ?></th>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>    
                        </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Any help is welcome :)
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What have you tried?  As is, your question is too broad. There are a large number of tutorials on how to do this on the internet.  Consult them and come back when you are facing a _specific_ problem

Comment: I added this to my code: see EDIT2

Comment: http status code: 500 refers to internal error. have u check the php logs?

Comment: What version of PHP do you have?  You are using OLD `mysql_*` based library functions. Should be using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` functions.